# Sistema Academico Java

Tags: java, herança, encapsulamento, polimorfismo

Olá..
Preciso de ajuda para montar um programa em Java com as seguintes especificações:

1) Ler, do usuário, os seguintes itens:
Nome(String), Idade(int), gênero(char[M ou F]), telefone(String), endereço(String), cpf(String), rg(String), bairro(String), cidade(String), uf(String), ra (se for um aluno)(String), curso (se for aluno)(String), rp(se for professor)(String), disciplina ministrada(se for professor)(String), salário(se for professor)(double).

2) É necessário criar uma classe chamada "Aluno", que possua os atributos de alunos. - Classe criada

```
package SistemaAcademico;

public class Aluno extends Pessoa {

    public Aluno(String nome, int idade, char genero, String telefone, String endereco, String cpf, String rg, String bairro, String cidade, String uf) {
        super(nome, idade, genero, telefone, endereco, cpf, rg, bairro, cidade, uf);
    }

    String ra;
    String curso;
}
```

3) É necessário criar uma classe chamada "Professor", que possua os atributos de professores. - Classe Criada

```
package SistemaAcademico;

public class Professor extends Pessoa {

    public Professor(String nome, int idade, char genero, String telefone, String endereco, String cpf, String rg, String bairro, String cidade, String uf) {
        super(nome, idade, genero, telefone, endereco, cpf, rg, bairro, cidade, uf);
    }

    String rp;
    String disciplinaMinistrada;
    double salario;
}
```

4) É necessário criar uma classe chamada "Pessoa", que possua os atributos comuns entre Alunos e Professores. - Classe criada

```
package SistemaAcademico;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private char genero;
    private String telefone;
    private String endereco;
    private String cpf;
    private String rg;
    private String bairro;
    private String cidade;
    private String uf;

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade, char genero, String telefone, String endereco, String cpf, String rg, String bairro, String cidade, String uf) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.rg = rg;
        this.bairro = bairro;
        this.cidade = cidade;
        this.uf = uf;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public char getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(char genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getUf() {
        return uf;
    }

    public void setUf(String uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }
}
```

5) A classe Pessoa deve possuir um método que sobrescreva o método "toString", de modo que imprima todos os dados de Pessoa.

6) Utilize o polimorfismo, para que a classe Aluno possa sobrescrever o método "toString", de modo que delegue à superclasse a escrita dos atributos da classe Pessoa e faça a impressão dos métodos exclusivos da classe Aluno.

7) Utilize o polimorfismo, para que a classe Professor possa sobrescrever o método "toString", de modo que delegue à superclasse a escrita dos atributos da classe Pessoa e faça a impressão dos métodos exclusivos da classe Professor.

(Aonde devo utilizar o toString em cada classe ?)

8) Crie um método com o nome de identificação na classe Principal, que possa ser chamado sem a necessidade de instanciar um objeto (ou seja, diretamente da classe). Esse método não deve receber parâmetros e deve imprimir a seguinte mensagem: "Nome do Aluno - RA do Aluno".

9) O usuário, ao inserir os dados, deve digitar 1 para inserir um Aluno ou 2 para inserir um Professor. Após selecionar o que quer inserir, deve-se apresentar os campos a serem inseridos do respectivo cadastro, ou seja, se for 1, todos os dados de Aluno, se for 2, todos os dados de professor. Os dados devem ser inseridos em uma variável do tipo selecionado. - Criado

```
package SistemaAcademico;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcao = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("##ESCOLHA UMA OPÇÃO\n");
            System.out.println("1 - Cadastrar Aluno");
            System.out.println("2 - Cadastrar Professor");
            System.out.println("3 - Sair\n");
            System.out.println("Digite uma opção: ");
            opcao = scan.nextInt();

            switch (opcao){
                case 1:
                    cadastro.cadastrarAluno();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cadastro.cadastrarProfessor();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Esta não é uma opção válida!");
            }
        } while (opcao !=3 );
    }
}
```

10) Após inserir os dados, o sistema deve imprimir os mesmos.

11) Regras a serem seguidas:
a) Não é permitido o cadastro de alunos menores de 18 anos. Deve-se mostrar uma mensagem solicitando que entre com a idade aceitável
b) Não é permitido o cadastro de professores menores de 21 anos. Deve-se mostrar uma mensagem solicitando que entre com a idade aceitável;

(Não sei aonde devo inserir estas regras)

Comment: Qual é dúvida em especifico? vc conseguiu resolver algum exercicio? Edite a pergunta e coloque em parte especifica vc tem problema ou dúvida.

Comment: A sua dúvida é no número 11 então?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Estamos aqui para ajudar, mas considere nas próximas vezes fazer perguntas mais específicas. Voc~e pode fazer quantas perguntas quiser. Fazendo-as separadas ajudar organizar e classificar o conteúdo, além de aumentar a chance de ajudar outras pessoas. Contamos com sua colaboração para aproveitar todo o potencial de ajuda do site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Você pode usar o showInputDialog() nas variáveis para fazer aparecer um dialog com um campo para digitar. Essa seria a maneira mais simples de receber os dados (sem ser pelo prompt, claro). Caso seja pelo prompt, use um objeto do tipo Scanner

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome do aluno");
```

Com Scanner:

```
in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Digite um nome: ");
String input = in.nextLine();
```

2 e 3) Procure pela estrutura básica de uma classe Java, também conhecida como POJO. Você ganharia muito tempo se também pudesse usar uma IDE como NetBeans ou Eclipse para isso.

4) Para isso, crie primeiro uma classe Pessoa, que você estará considerando como a classe pai de Aluno e Professor. O ideal é que dados como "nome, idade, gênero..." (todos que ambos Alunos e Professores podem possuir) estejam nessa classe. Procure por exemplos de herança em Java.

5) Para sobreescrever toString, apenas adicione o metódo na classe desejada (no caso, Pessoa). Basta usar **this.Atributo** para referenciar os atributos desejados no retorno.

```
public String toString() { 
return "Name: '" + this.name + "', Height: '" + this.height + "', Birthday: '" + this.bDay + "'"; }
```

6) Você escreveu métodos, mas creio que você esteja se referindo à atributos. Basta criar um toString() dentro de Aluno onde você apenas referenciará os atributos que a classe Pessoa não tem. (Por exemplo, RA).

7) Mesma coisa, agora com os dados/atributos exclusivos da classe Professor.

8) Sabe quando você começa a escrever o método? Para que seja possível chamá-lo sem instanciar um objeto, adicione static no cabeçalho.

```
public static int MeuMetodo() {}
```

E para chamar, basta chamá-lo a partir da classe.

```
ClasseAluno.MeuMetodo()
```

9)Isso é lógica de programação pura. Você só precisa criar linhas de execução para cada caso. Exemplo bem simples de um if:

```
if(numero == 1) {
   // Faça o recebimento de aluno aqui 
} else if(numero == 2) {
   //Faça o recebimento do professor aqui
}else {
   System.out.println("Digite 1 ou 2!")
}
```

10)Use o System.out.println em um **for** ou **while**, desde que ele passe por todos os atributos de quem está sendo inserido/foi inserido. Tranquilo.

11)Lembra do if que eu te mostrei na **questão 9**? Simplesmente adicione essas restrições no fluxo do programa, idealmente após o recebimento da variável de idade.

Espero ter ajudado. Creio que com essas informações e, considerando que são apenas esses os requisitos, você conseguirá terminar tudo rapidinho. (usando, é claro, **if**)